# Estimate cell weights in a 2D grid based on their distance to a random point

Tags: math, datagrid, interpolation

I have a discrete grid of cells of size `n_X * n_Y`, where the center cell is located at `(0,0)`
. In this grid, there is a random point at `(x_target, y_target)` with respect to the center, that can change its position over time.

I want to give to each cell a certain weight between 0 and 1 based on how close are to the random point. The furthest points should be `0` and the closest points should be `1`. The intermadiate cells should interpolate between both base on their distance.

The system:

[image]

Do you know how I could estimate each cell's weight, assuming that the furtherst points are 0 and closest are 1, in addition to know the position of the random point? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate maximal distance `dmax` from that random point to grid corner.

Then for every cell find distance to random point `d` and make weight

```
wt = 1 - (d - 1) / (dmax - 1)
```

(I added -1 to provide value 1.0 for the closest cell layer with distance 1)

Comment: Given the image provided by the OP, I assume "distance" is meant as Manhattan distance, ie distance between A(xa,ya) and B(xb,yb) would be `abs(xb-xa)+abs(yb-ya)`? Also, how do you choose which grid corner to use to calculate `dmax`? If you choose the furthest? In that case there might be a big jump near the closest corner. But if you choose the closest, then there will be negative values near the furthest corner.

Comment: Of course, I meant the farthest corner. Problem statement is not fully specified -  text says only about distance, but picture shows zeros at all corners, and what about borders? In any case, author have to use some initial model, then develop it to get better results.